# How can i make a date reminder with javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I don't know much about javascript. So please help me guys.

How can i set a countdown for March 1, 2013 3:00:00 AM?

Like;

Before the date: x days x time x minutes left

On the date: yay, its March 1

After the date: You missed the day :(

I've posted a question before but i didn't describe it well. I hope i did this time. Please help. I really need to set a countdown on my webpage (HTML)

Comment: In what context? On a web site? On a server? Persistent?

Answer (score 1):

With this code you can know how much day left from date1 to date2

```
var date1 = new Date("Feb 3 2013 10:49:00");
var date2 = new Date("Feb 4 2013 10:49:00");

var days = (date2 - date1) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
document.write( "remain "  + days + " to <b>" +date2 + "</b>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=new Date();
x.setFullYear(2013,2,1);
var today = new Date();

if (x>today)
  {
  alert("You missed the day.");
  }
else if (x<today)
  {
  alert("x day left");
  }
else {
  alert("This is the day");
  }
```

You only need to compute X days left.

(2013,2,1) means 1 March, 2013 in JavaScript. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Wow thank you :) and sorry, what do i have to do with X? Not familiar with JS

Comment: Oh my bad. Can you edit it? I want it as only text. Not alert :) Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The whole internet? Man, that's a lot of searching.

[This is on the internet, too.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

```
var x=new Date();
x.setFullYear(2013,2,1);
var today = new Date();

if (x>today) {
    alert("Today is before March 1st, 2013");
} else {
    alert("Today is after March 1st, 2013");
}
```

Comment: touche, thats what i get for responding before 9 am.